# How to make border bottom color above border right color?

Tags: html, css

In the example below the border right color takes precedence over the border bottom color.

[image]

Is there a way to make the horizontal border line to flow without interruption over the vertical lines?

```css
table th,
table td {
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(229, 231, 235);
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(229, 231, 235);
}

table th {
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(156, 163, 175);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Which result are you expecting? https://nimb.ws/MNZgBq or your image?

Comment: In chrome I can see the dark grey line uninterupted, in Edge 91 it looks like on the image in your post (interrupted by the light grey borders).

Comment: @m4n0 expecting the horizontal line uninterrupted, like on this image you pusted nimb.ws/MNZgBq

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```css
table th,
table td {
  border-right: 10px solid rgba(229, 231, 235);
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(229, 231, 235);
}
table tr{
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(229, 231, 235);
}
table th {
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(156, 163, 175);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it works in Firfox but not in Chrome.